# Scala typeclass pattern and covariance

Tags: scala, covariance, typeclass

We've got several types of resources and we wanted to make a method to check if a resource is healthy or not. Given that the type of resources are very heterogeneous we didn't want to use standard subclassing and we decided to use a typeclass:

```
trait CanHealthCheck[T] {
  def isHealthy(t: T): Boolean
}
```

We also have a utility method to be able to check if a given resource is alive/healthy or not

```
object LivenessChecker {
  def isAlive[T](t: T)(implicit canHealthCheck: CanHealthCheck[T]): Boolean = {
    canHealthCheck.isHealthy(t)
  }
}
```

We've got a repository layer to access to the data. We would like to express the idea that a given abstract repository must be "health checkable" but to leave the implementation details to the subclasses implementing the trait:

```
trait UserRepository {
  def findSomeUser(): User = ???

  implicit def isHealthCheckable: CanHealthCheck[UserRepository]
}
```

The problem arises when we want to subclass UserRepository with a particular implementation, given that CanHealthCheck is not **covariant** on the type **T**.

```
class DbUserRepository extends UserRepository {
  def ping: Boolean = ???

  override implicit val isHealthCheckable: CanHealthCheck[UserRepository] = 
    new CanHealthCheck[DbUserRepository] {
      def isHealthy(db: DbUserRepository) = db.ping
    }
}
```

And this is an example of some dummy function that acts on the abstract repository while trying to check if the repository is alive:

```
def someDummyFunction(userRepository: UserRepository) = {
  if(LivenessChecker.isAlive(userRepository)) // This won't compile
    userRepository.findSomeUser()
}
```

The idea is that our application uses the **UserRepository** trait and not the implementation, and thus we cannot check whether the repository is alive or not. How can we continue using the repository abstraction layer and be able to check if a given (abstract) repository is alive? Is the typeclass pattern the correct pattern to use here?

Answer (score 2):

There is something a bit fishy with `isHealthCheckable` inside `UserRespository`. The `isHealthy` method, when called, would have two instances of `UserRepository` available: of course, the one passed as the `t` argument, but also, the `UserRepository.this` of the enclosing instance.

This is a sign of something wrong. Either the method should be written somewhere else, so that it does not get enclosing this, or it should not get the argument

That second option is consistent with using UserRepository the object-oriented, subtyping way. Also, it is consistent with your idea that every UserRepository must be heath-checkable. Just do

```
trait UserRepository {
  ...
  def isHealty: Boolean
}
```

It is fine to call that directly, `userDirectory.isHealthy`. But you can then also easily implement the type class:

```
object UserRepository {
  implicit val canHealthCheck = new CanHealthCheck[UserRepository] {
    def isHealthy(repository: UserRepository) = repository.IsHealthy
  }
}
```

also note that it was not clear at all how the implicit instance method would have come into the implicit scope. With the companion object, it works fine.

Comment: I agree that is probably a sign of something wrong. The question is if we can use the typeclass pattern and having clients depend only on the trait, or we need to use the classical OO oriented approach. BTW I updated the question to reflect how a potential client would use the abstract userRepository

Answer (score 0):

Use "type bounds".

I couldn't test this, but to get the code to compile, you could do something like:

```
class DbUserRepository[U <: UserRepository] extends UserRepository {
   def ping: Boolean = ???

   implicit val isHealthCheckable: CanHealthCheck[U] =
     new CanHealthCheck[U] {
       def isHealthy(db: U) = db.ping
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this solve the problem. We need a `CanHealthCheck[UserRepository]` whereas in your example we get a `CanHealthCheck[U]`with `U<:UserRepository`. Given that CanHealthCheck is not **covariant** on T, this won't work

Comment: I am sorry, I missed "CanHealthCheck is not covariant on the type T" in your question. I'll leave the answer as a reference as to how to get the code to compile...for now :-\